# SSAS cube process time increased after making fact and dimension small

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, olap, process

I have a cube of 55 GB size which takes around 2 Hour to process full. As I have data for last 4 years but our business wants only 2 years of data.
For that, I have changed dimension and Fact views to have only last two years of data. Now, my cube size is reduced to 32 GB but processing time increased by 30 min (i.e. 2 hours 30 min). I was expecting it to be less as I have restricted good amount of data going into the cube.
Why the processing time has increased when it should actually decrease? 
How can I reduce processing time now?

P.S.: I have already tried cube partition and due to large dimension size it is also increasing processing time.

I am using views where I have restricted the data via WHERE clause.

My view is basically like this:

```
SELECT V.Col1, V.Col2.... V.Col13 
FROM DimeTable V 
WHERE <my filter clause>
```

It is selecting almost all columns from the dimension table so I can't create non clustered index on all these columns as it may slow down insert operation and won't help me much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Processing a cube largely consists of 3 steps,

1. Getting the data
2. building indexes
3. calculating aggregations

Step 2 and 3 are the least expensive (during processing) in my opinion so let's start with that.

Building indexes does little more than calculating bitmap indexes for your attribute relationships. So depending on how many of those you have designed this could take longer or not, but usually shouldn't take half an hour. This does little more than saying "hey if this item group is filtered on, I already know what Items are in it, so I can add those up instead of doing a `NONEMTPTYCROSSJOIN`"

Calculating aggregations is the process in which the subtotals are calculated for every level where you defined them. If you haven't used any `usage based optimization` or `attribute hierarchies` and haven't defined any aggregations yourself those are only calculated on the leaf level of your dimensions hierarchies (aka the lowest level of every attribute). This is basically "hey if I need the sales for this item group I have precalculated it and don't have to add up these items"

A large part of processing time is used while fetching data. If you would trace your queries while processing you would notice that for every single dimension attribute a `SELECT DISTINCT attributename FROM dimension_table` is executed. If that dimension table is a view, and the query from the view is slower after adding a where, that dimension processing might become slower by `time_the_view_is_slower * number_of_attributes`.
How many columns are in the select list of your view is largely irrelevant, the number of attributes in your dimension **is**.

If you have a `distinct count` measure anywhere your extra where could have inserted a sort operation too because of a new execution plan.

So in your case my guess would be that your dimension views have gotten slower due to the fact that the valid date isn't indexed, or the queries aren't selective enough and the added processing time of the source queries exaggerates the reduced time of building indexes and aggregations.

You most likely have improved your cube browsing and MDX performance in the process by reducing the number of cells calculated with less data in the cube, but the processing time may just have grown by creating slower source queries, and that gets multiplied by the number of attributes.

Then again, I'm not sure what the problem is with larger processing times if you leave everything default. The performance of the SSAS solution should be more important than the processing time. If you run in to issues due to the processing time that might be another problem that needs fixing in another way.

So I guess, in the end, If you're worried about processing time, either load less data in your source database (which, depending on your setup, could reduce ETL loading time) or tune all those distinct queries by indexing your view accordingly.

If you want to know what exactly is slowing down your processing you could trace all the queries before and after the change and compare the execution times to see what queries are killing you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. +1. I have a question here. My views select almost all columns from my dimension or fact table. Will it be good to have index view? I mean, a non-clustered on where and rest all columns included? 
Nevertheless, today I will try to have indexes on that. May be columnstore.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity that's hard to tell what your best solution is without having more specifics. If you have a ETL process and a datamart I would try loading less data into it, if your cube connects to your live database directly I would be very careful about the impact on the business application. Don't break the performance of your business system for your SSAS processing time

Comment: I agree. I have a data load to data mart every 6 hours with about 20k new rows and 40k updates. I'm going to create columnstore indexes on the table after the load and would disable it before loading data into mart. Hopefully, I will be able to reduce the performance. I will get back here again with performance stats. Please do post here if you have any suggestion for me.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity try to find your worst offenders and try to optimize those first. Test if your changes actually help. There is no point in slapping new stuff on the database without knowing what query you are trying to improve. Plus it's easier to test a query than to process the cube

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity did you make any progress?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. I tried indexing (columnstore too) but none of them helped me decreasing the processing time. I have views which are selecting almost every column from the table. Is there any other way to decrease processing time? I have also tried increasing **number of connection** from 10 to 32 but that is also not helping. Nevertheless, I really appreciate you followed my question.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity Did you trace which queries take longest? Trying is guessing

Comment: Queries are taking almost 5-15 min. 15 min for those dimension which has huge amount of data and 5 min for small dimension. As I have primary key defined on the identity key and I can see that SQL Server has generate a simple execution plan for that. I don't think I can optimize that. Nevertheless, I appreciate your response & I've marked this as an answer because what you have answered is perfectly valid.

Comment: Just in case, if you find any other way to optimize performance then please let me know.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity when seeing the word 'optimizing', one usually expects an actual query execution plan.  Could you add one to your question?